# Elasticsearch: can't create an index after upgrade to 7.9.3 (mapper_parsing_exception)

Tags: elasticsearch

I've upgraded my cluster from 6.8 to 7.93 and I can't create indices anymore
At first I thought there was a problem with my default mapping but I get a *mapper_parsing_exception* even without specifying a mapping

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/test-index?pretty
```

results in

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_all : {enabled=false}]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_all : {enabled=false}]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_all : {enabled=false}]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I realize the _all meta field isn't supported on ES 7 anymore and here is the default mapping I had planned for ES 7 (creating an index with it doesn't work either)

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "data": {
        "type": "text",
        "index": false
      },
      "metadata": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "date": {
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
            "type": "date"
          },
          "reception_date": {
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
            "type": "date"
          },
          "source": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "env": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "keyword"
          "filename": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": false
          "ts_ms": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "ts": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I do not have this error on the testing instance on my PC which is running in docker. Tests run fine when I build the project on a test instance. It appears to be specifically failing only on the cluster. On the cluster there are ES 6 indices living. What can possibly cause this mapping error ? Is it possible that there is a setting inherited from ES 6 that causes this ?

Here is the not-so-pretty java traceback from my logs

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_all : {enabled=false}]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.internalMerge(MapperService.java:390) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.merge(MapperService.java:351) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetadataCreateIndexService.updateIndexMappingsAndBuildSortOrder(MetadataCreateIndexService.java:913) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetadataCreateIndexService.lambda$applyCreateIndexWithTemporaryService$5(MetadataCreateIndexService.java:399) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.withTempIndexService(IndicesService.java:620) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetadataCreateIndexService.applyCreateIndexWithTemporaryService(MetadataCreateIndexService.java:397) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetadataCreateIndexService.applyCreateIndexRequestWithV1Templates(MetadataCreateIndexService.java:483) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetadataCreateIndexService.applyCreateIndexRequest(MetadataCreateIndexService.java:360) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetadataCreateIndexService.applyCreateIndexRequest(MetadataCreateIndexService.java:367) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetadataCreateIndexService$1.execute(MetadataCreateIndexService.java:290) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateUpdateTask.execute(ClusterStateUpdateTask.java:47) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.executeTasks(MasterService.java:702) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.calculateTaskOutputs(MasterService.java:324) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.runTasks(MasterService.java:219) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.access$000(MasterService.java:73) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService$Batcher.run(MasterService.java:151) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher.runIfNotProcessed(TaskBatcher.java:150) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher$BatchedTask.run(TaskBatcher.java:188) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:678) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:252) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:215) [elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_all : {enabled=false}]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.checkNoRemainingFields(DocumentMapperParser.java:148) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:88) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:74) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.internalMerge(MapperService.java:388) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Do you have any index template set up? i.e. what do you get when calling `GET _template` ?

Comment: THANK YOU this solved it. There were a couple of old index templates set on the cluster dating from before the upgrade. I deleted them and it's all good now.

Comment: is there an easy way to find out which index template is clashing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have old index templates that are interfering when you create new indexes.

Try to `GET _template` and see if there are any incompatible mapping parameters that you can change to make it work.

Eventually, delete old unused templates.